# Laravel сервис контейнер не работает в объектах созданных вручную?

Tags: php, laravel

Насколько я понял, laravel подтягивает зависимости, только для экшенов контроллеров, а дальше, когда в контроллере создается объект вручную через new и дальше по цепочке вниз контейнер уже не работает?

Может быть есть какой-то создающий объекты паттерн, который позволяет сохранить работу контейнера?

```
Controller {
  new obj(); // ошибка - не переданы зависимости
  
  $a = new a(тоже зависимости);
  $b = new b();
  new obj($a, $b); // конструктор должен принимать параметры, они сами не загрузятся из контейнера т.к все создано вручную и нужно делать по старинке

}

Class obj {
  public function __construct(объект $a, объект $b)
    {
      т.к объект $a передан вручную у него тоже зависимости в его конструктор автоматом подтягиваться не будут?
    }
}
```

Comment: ну а с чего ему вдруг работать при ручном создании? Чем создание простого объекта в ларавел отличается от такого же создания в пустом пхп файле? Прочитайте раздел документации, там вроде все описано https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container как биндить и как создавать экземпляры

Comment: @teran
Есть какой то выход, чтобы после создания первого объекта вручную последующие были уже с привязкой контейнера?

Comment: вы прочитали документацию? Там вроде написано, как сделать так чтобы контейнер узнал о ваших классах и правильно их инстанциировал, также написано как создавать экземпляры через контейнер, а не прямым вызовом конструктора.